# SQL SELECT returns what a appears to be a empty field when there is data in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

When I run a select on a field it appears to be blank in SSMS, however I know there is data in it.

e.g. `Select [Field] from [Table]` returns:

| Field |
| --- |
|  |
|  |

However I know there should be data in it. This should be **AT000** and **AT001** in this instance.

I have run the follwing to confirm this:

```
SELECT 

[Field],

datalength([Field]) AS 'Data Length',

CAST([Field] AS varbinary) AS 'Varbinray' ,

CAST(SUBSTRING(CAST([Field] AS VARBINARY(MAX)),2,DATALENGTH([Field])-2) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'CASTSS'

FROM [Table]
```

And this returns

| Field | Data Length | Varbinary | CASTSS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 10 | 0x00410054003000300031 | AT00 |
|  | 10 | 0x00410054003000300030 | AT00 |

This is close to what I am trying to get to, but do you know how I get that last number onto the field?

Comment: The problem is your value has `NULL` characters, and many applications (SSMS included) treat a `NULL` character as the *end* of the string. As your first character in the string is a `NULL` character, nothing is displayed.

Comment: If you remove the `NULL` characters (giving `0x4154303031`) then you get the value you want (`'AT001'`). Most likely you need to fix what ever process is putting the data into your database with `NULL` characters first, before you try to fix your data.

Comment: FYI, the binary values are AT000 and AT001 encoded as big-endian Unicode. Looks like an encoding issue with the app that inserts the values.

Comment: You are right, I am able to get what I am looking for by using a REPLACE(CAST([Field] as varchar(max)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, CHAR(0),'') I agree that ideally preventing the app from loading this in the first place would be best however our vendor is not the most accommodating on these things! Thanks for your help @Larnu

Comment: Be careful that this approach will still result in garbled text if there are any characters with code points greater than 255 present, since you're just throwing away all-bits-zero octets and then hoping the rest can be interpreted as Latin-1. For a proper approach you'd need to convert the big-endian Unicode used here to little-endian Unicode and then interpret it as an `NVARCHAR`. Unfortunately the endian conversion can't be done in T-SQL, at least not in a simple or efficient way (a CLR function is probably the best way if it has to be done in the DB).

Comment: You *could* do something crazy like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/OVdp58U_), but it would fail the moment you have a character that required 3 (or more) bytes to be represented.

Comment: @Larnu: fortunately that's never going to be the case for UTF-16 data -- this isn't UTF-8. At best you'd get surrogate characters, but those would be handled correctly after the endian correction, assuming you use a surrogate-aware collation. Solutions like these are what I had in mind with "no simple or efficient way" -- especially since we're talking about SQL Server 2016 so `STRING_AGG` is not available.